# Auto update table fields and disabled function using javaScript, Ruby on Rails and/or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

### Versions

Mac OS: OSX 10.10.2
Ruby: 2.2.1p85
Rails: 4.2.0
Bootstrap-SASS: 3.3.4  #For Web UI
Bootstrap-Switch-Rails: 3.0.0   #For Toggles

### Context

I am building a site where someone can create a packing event to make bags for the homeless. I am using Ruby on Rails to create this webapp, Bootstrap to design the user interface, and am open to using JQuery, javaScript, HTML, and CSS to get the desired functionality. Though my working knowledge of the first two languages is minimal.

In the user's event creation and edit pages I have a list of items that a person can add to their bags. This list is in a table view as seen through the link below.

[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glx55rc8ag342ol/example%20webapp%20Table.png?dl=0)

### Desired Functionality

I am wanting to do 2 things.

1. When the user enters the number of bags they plan on packing, I want to be able to update the column "Number Needed" for each item. So, for instance in the example scenario shown in the image above, the "Number Needed" for "Raise Money" would be "$6,500", for "Volunteers" would not be added, for "Water" would be "1000" and for "Food" would be "1000".
2. I want the user to be able to toggle whether to include an item on their event page. So, in the example picture, the user wants to show on their event page that they are raising money for their event, and requesting donations for water and food; but they do not need volunteers to pack the bags. In this scenario, I would like to disable the form fields of "Number Needed", "Currently Have" and "Number Remaining to Get" for the row "Volunteers".

### Questions

1. For the first desired functionality specified above: Should I just have the table on a separate page maybe so that the fields are populated before the table is actually shown? Or, my preferred ability, do I need to put a button after the "Number of Bags" field that when clicked updates the table? And how would I do that?
2. For the second desired functionality specified above: Is there a way to have this done dynamically when the user toggles the "Include" column to "Yes" or "No"? How would I disable the desired form fields dynamically once a user toggles that row to "No"?

Let me know if you need any more information. And thank you in advance for your expertise.

Comment: first try to do it by yourself there are lots of guides on the internet, and when you have trouble with the code show us the code you've written..
here are some pretty good courses
http://www.codecademy.com/
https://www.codeschool.com/

Comment: Thank you @SantiagoSuárez, I actually have been researching the topic for the past few hours, then posted this question and continued to research. I am not finding much. I don't know if I am searching with the wrong keywords or what. But, I will continue to do research and post something if I can.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I would put this in the comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do that yet.

Ok so there's a few ways to solve your problem. The first and ugly solution would be to rerender the page everytime something gets updated. You really shouldn't do it that way because that required the user to hit a button to submit the form and the controller would render the same page again with updated results.

Instead, you want to use jQuery to add event listeners to your form fields and the button mentioned in the second functionality. On those event listeners, put some handlers to update the desired field. It's hard to direct you on the jQuery if I don't know your HTML structure. As Santiago mentioned, there are many tutorials out on the internet for putting event listeners and creating the proper handlers.

Additionally, you should consider AJAX to asynchronously communicate with your controller to keep the front-end (what the users see on the browser) and the back-end (data stored in the database) in sync. Again, plenty of guides out there on the internet for this, but definitely look into the Rails functionality of "remote: true" on your form to make the set up of the AJAX process easier.

Comment: Thank you, @Snags88. I will definitely look into those solutions.